# Preciso somar algumas linhas específicas em um data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, soma

Preciso somar o valor das linhas no qual aparece "Resposnsável C', de modo prático eu preciso somar as linhas 3, 4 e 9 a partir da coluna 2, o resultado deverá ser  112. Até o momento consegui printar as linhas que quero usando o iloc, mas não consigo soma-las. Segue o código.
ps: Preciso somar o que está em vermelho.

```
import pandas as pd
def trans_excel_py(arquivocsv):
    df = pd.read_csv(arquivocsv, sep=';', header = None)
    return df
def soma_colunas(arquivocsv):
    df = pd.read_csv(arquivocsv, sep=';')
    matriz = pd.DataFrame(df.values)
    somas = []
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        Total = matriz[i].sum()
        somas.append(Total)
    return somas
teste = trans_excel_py('cronograma.csv')
print(teste)
teste_sum = soma_colunas("cronograma.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame([teste_sum[2:10]],columns=['S1', 'S2', 'S3','S4','S5','S6','S7','S8'])
print("\n",df)

print(sum(teste_sum[2:10]))

df1 = teste.iloc[[3,4,9]]
print("\n",df1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Após selecionar as linhas, como você fez:

```
df1 = teste.iloc[[3,4,9]]

df2 = df1.sum(axis=1) # soma cada linha individualmente no eixo horizontal

df2.sum() # soma os resultados de cada linha
```

Também é possível fazer tudo em apenas uma linha:

```
teste.iloc[[3,4,9]].sum(axis=1).sum()
```

Mais informações estão na documentação:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Para selecionar também as colunas que serão usadas (da 2 até a 9):

```
teste[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]].iloc[[3,4,9]].sum(axis=1).sum()
```

Você também pode substituir os `NaN` por algum valor usando `fillna(valor)`:

```
teste[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]].iloc[[3,4,9]].fillna(0).sum(axis=1).sum()
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo, ele não retornou resultado nenhum... Não é que está errado ele só não retorna a soma do que está em vermelho. Tentei com apenas um linha (a 3 que deveria me retornar a resposta da soma como 24) mas no final ele me resultou como 0.0. Pra ser mais específica eu não quero a soma da linha toda, apenas a soma da linha que vai da coluna 2 até a coluna 9.